# Moving data from Solr 1.5 to Solr 4.0

Tags: lucene, solr

We've lot of data indexed with Solr 1.5. Since this version is not supported anymore, we would like to move to Solr 4.0 trunk. I can easily download all Solr results into an .XML file (already done that, it's over 40Gb in size) and then run xslt transformation to convert solr results XML into Solr update XML (using XSLTC of course), but is there any other "standard" way to transfer data between solr nodes? Something like a dump.

Putting XSLT code here for reference:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/response/result">
    <add>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <commit/>
    </add>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="doc">
    <doc>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </doc>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="arr/str">
    <xsl:element name="field">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="str">
<xsl:element name="field">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem? I have the same task now and am searching for possible caveats during update. Also, out of curiosity: how happened that you have asked this question on December 2010 when 4.0-alpha version was released only in July 2012?

Comment: I've used trunk version of solr 4.0 (which was prior to alpha). Yes we solved that problem by extracting data into multiple XML files (one per one document) and storing them back to Solr 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to copy the index binaries ($SOLR_HOME/data) to the new node. Besides that, the standard way would probably be to replicate the index using [Solr replication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication), but I doubt it would be easier than just copying the index manually.

Comment: I tried copying already. It says something about incompatibility of data format (looks like Solr 1.5 Use Lucene 2.X while Solr 4.0 use Lucene 3.0)

Comment: Check your solrconfig for the <luceneMatchVersion> element, and make sure it matches what your old solr instance was using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a Copy-out-of-the-box method. We have implemented something with stx but it isn't open source.

Another way to do it is via SolrJ, this way you can take advantage of all nice Java methods. (with this you could do even a "streaming read" and "streaming write", but this would involve two SolrJ binaries to be in the classpath and will cause you a lot of trouble.)

So, set the parsing + writing to xml and you won't have a problem:

```
server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
server.setRequestWriter(...;
```

For an example I'm refering to the [jetwick](http://jetwick.com/) project. Setting the parser + writer is done in [SolrAbstractSearch](https://github.com/karussell/Jetwick/blob/master/src/main/java/de/jetwick/solr/SolrAbstractSearch.java)

Take a look into [this class](https://github.com/karussell/Jetwick/blob/master/src/main/java/de/jetwick/solr/Util.java) for the copy method. Then you'll have to change the createDoc and readDoc method in [SolrTweetSearch](https://github.com/karussell/Jetwick/blob/master/src/main/java/de/jetwick/solr/SolrTweetSearch.java)

Comment: As to me XSLT solution is much simpler.

Comment: ok, no prob. make this the solution and you'll get up votes :-)